# How to disable button until user input numbers in Otp field in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
 <v-otp-input
            ref="otpInput"
            input-classes="otp-number"
            separator=" "
            :num-inputs="4"
            :should-auto-focus="true"
            :is-input-num="true"
            
          />
 <button class="verify-button" v-on:click="isFadeout = true"  :disabled="v-otp-input.length < 4" >VERIFY
 </button>
```

How to disable verify button until user input numbers in Otp field, Tried placing :disabled="v-otp-input.length < 4.

Comment: Show more code. `v-otp-input.length < 4` should work IF you have a `v-otp-input` field in `data` and your `v-otp-input` component is using that field as `v-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@on-change` or `@on-complete`.

Please try like this.

```
<v-otp-input
    ref="otpInput"
    input-classes="otp-number"
    separator=" "
    :num-inputs="4"
    :should-auto-focus="true"
    :is-input-num="true"
    @on-change="handleOnChange"
    @on-complete="handleOnComplete"
/>
<button class="verify-button" v-on:click="isFadeout = true"  :disabled="!otp_complete" >VERIFY</button>

...
data() {
    return {
      otp_value: '',
      otp_complete: false
},
methods: {
    handleOnComplete(value) {
      this.otp_complete = true;
      this.otp_value = value;
    },
    handleOnChange(value) {
      this.otp_value = value;
    },
},
...
```

You can use also `otp_value`to disable the button.

```
<button class="verify-button" v-on:click="isFadeout = true"  :disabled="otp_value.length < 4" >VERIFY</button>
```